# how to reuse a fragment for both activity and tablet

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a fragment which is in the layout file. It works great with an activity. How can i make this same fragment appear in a tablet ?

I tried to create a dynamic fragment, but that didnt seem to work

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Fragment will appear in your layout on all devices unless you specifically override your primary layout files in a qualified resource folder. [This section of the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) provides an overview of the main idea, as well as a list of available qualifiers.